# How to solve this Constraints error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have `table1` with 3 columns: `id varchar(20)`, `name`, `mother_id varchar(20)`. `mother_id` is a foreign key referring to the `id` column in the same table.

Here is my table:

```
|id     |name    |mother_id|  
|dog1   |my_dog  | (null)    
|dog2   |my_dog2 | dog1    
|dog3   |my_dog3 | dog1
```

If I tried  to update `dog1` and change `dog4` I have this error:

```
 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dogs`.`table1`, CONSTRAINT `FK_dogs1` FOREIGN KEY (`mother_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

How to solve this problem? I'm using `wamp 2.0 h` and `Sqlyog` enterprise.

Comment: You should supply the sql query in question to be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly change a `Primary key` value which is referenced by a `Foreign key` value.
but there is multi ways to change it one way is:

**drop** the Foreign key constraint and Primary key **->** **update** the values (PK and FK) **->** and then **add** the primary key and Foreign Key constraint again

```
alter table table1 drop foreign key thenameofFK;
alter table table1 drop primary key;

update table1
set id='dog4'
where id='dog1';

update table1 
set mother_id='dog4'
where mother_id='dog1';

alter table table1  add primary key(id);
alter table table1 
add constraint thenameofFK
foreign key(mother_id)
references table1(id);
```

also please remove PHP tag from question, I don't see any issue or content related to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change it in php myadmin drop the Foreign key constraint and Primary key -> update the values (PK and FK) -> and then add the primary key and Foreign Key constraint again